# pywinauto: accessing chrome gui

Tags: google-chrome, pywinauto

I am trying to select a printer and print on chrome browser, using pywinauto, but I am not able to access the gui components. I can see the components in Microsoft Inspect.exe in UIAutomation mode. (See screenshot).

I have started chrome with `--force-renderer-accessibility` flag.

I tried several things but I am not able to access anything in the chrome window. Is it possible to access the chrome gui components using pywinauto?

screenshot: [image: ![Screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8hCS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you use default `backend="win32"` which is used when you call `Application()`. To use MS UI Automation you have to set `backend="uia"` when instantiating Application object:

```
 app = Application(backend='uia').start('chrome.exe <other params>')
```

My student wrote [example script](https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/ui-automation-course/blob/master/02_google_drive_Murashov/test_explorer_google_drive.py) dragging file from `explorer.exe` to Google Drive in Chrome. Is it working for you?

P.S. If you already use `backend='uia'`, please provide more detailed description with some code and output.

Comment: hi @vasily.. hope you are doing great! yes, I used backend='uia'.. I will update the question with code and output tomorrow. really late here. I will also check the example script. thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The example script helped a lot and now I can access the gui elements. Earlier, I was starting chrome with selenium webdriver giving `--force-renderer-accessibility` parameter and then I was connecting to the application using Application.connect.. I am sure I was doing something wrong. But not involving selenium is better approach for me and it is also working for me so I will stick with it. Thanks a lot, again!