# PyWinAuto: Process not found

Tags: python, google-chrome, pywinauto, python-webbrowser

I am trying to automate saving each tab in my open browser (Google Chrome). This code used to work before when it operated from the command prompt, but now I am making a GUI to use the functions and I get this error.

here is the function that uses Application.connect().

```
# saves all current tabs to clipboard and closes browser
    def save_and_close(self):
        global URLS

        # list that contains new URLS for storage
        updated_data = []

        # account for any internet-related disconnections
        try:
            app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path = self.browser_location)
            find_windows(title = "Google Chrome")

            while True:
                try:
                    keyboard.send_keys("{F6}^c")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    updated_data.append(clipboard.GetData())
                    time.sleep(3)
                    keyboard.send_keys("^w")
                    time.sleep(3)

                except KeyboardInterrupt:

                    keyboard.send_keys("^") # undo the keyboard control key
                    break 

            # updates database with new URLS
            with open("bmanager.json", "w") as dw:
                json.dump(updated_data, dw)

            # reloads database for next possible usage
            URLS = json.loads(open("bmanager.json").read())

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print ("[ERROR]: Client is not connected to the internet")
```

Here is the error:

```
Process [browser location] not found!
```

Note that [browser location] is just a placeholder for the location of my browser's .exe file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pywinauto: accessing chrome gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562222/pywinauto-accessing-chrome-gui)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I actually figured out the problem, which happened to be a bug with global variables in my program. Thanks for your efforts though!

Comment: Great. Please answer your own question and accept it (gray check box at the left side of answer should work for you). On StackOverflow it's normal way to show others the problem is already resolved (resolved question is green in a tag feed).

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, let me tell you I admire your reactivity. It's been so many years now. Please tell me, when will you admit your tool is now a classic and deserves to be celebrated with a "version 1 party"? :D

Comment: The next major release will be 0.7.0 with Linux and macOS support. Then we have plans for script recorder on all OSes. Maybe it will be 0.8.0 and 0.9.0.

Comment: Version 1.0.0 will most likely have new backend on Windows based on managed DLL injection. It should help to support custom .NET controls using internal programmatic names. But this research is not started yet. You see there is still long way to “version 1 party”. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I have to register chrome using the location and pywinauto's register function before connecting to it.